# WSO2 AM - Converting JSON to XML

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I want to expose the REST API in **WSO2 API Manager** with the back-end service (*XML over http*). I wanted to convert the JSON request to XML and call my back-end service.

Please let me know how to achieve this in **WSO2 API Manager 3.0**

Answer (score 2):

Use the json-to-xml-in-message mediation sequence.

1. Login to api publisher.
2. Open the api and go to the Runtime Configurations tab from the left menu.
3. In the Request section, click on Edit button of the Message Mediation option.
4. Select the json-to-xml-in-message mediation sequence from the Common Policies.
5. Click on Select and Save the api.

   [image]